# Unexpected value on multiplication in javascript

Tags: javascript, multiplication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [understanding floating point variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480699/understanding-floating-point-variables)

I tried multiplying 15.95 * 3 and was expecting a result 47.85. But the result was surprising(47.849999999999994).

In some other cases also it is happening
Ex: 10.65 * 3 = 31.950000000000003
10.55 * 3 = 31.650000000000002

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Thank you

Comment: Also `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3`. That's because of floating point numbers.

Comment: I believe the answer your looking for is here...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken