# Javascript multiplying incorrectly, causing incorrect rounding

Tags: javascript, math, parsefloat

When I pull the values I want to multiply, they're strings. So I pull them, parse them as floats (to preserve the decimal places), and multiply them together.

```
LineTaxRate = parseFloat(myRate) * parseFloat(myQuantity) * parseFloat(myTaxRateRound);
```

This has worked for 99% of my invoices but I discovered one very odd problem.

When it multiplied: **78 * 7 * 0.0725**

Javascript is returning: **39.584999999999994**

When you normally do the math in a calculator its: **39.585**

When all is said and done, I take that number and round it using **.toFixed(2)**

Because Javascript is returning that number, it's not rounding to the desired value of: **$39.59**

I tried **Math.round()** the total but I still get the same number.

I have thought of rounding the number to 3 decimals then two, but that seems hacky to me.

I have searched everywhere and all I see is people mention parseFloat loses its precision, and to use .toFixed, however in the example above, that doesn't help.

Here is my test script i made to recreate the issue:

```
<script>
var num1 = parseFloat("78");
var num2 = parseFloat("7");
var num3 = parseFloat("0.0725");
var myTotal = num1 * num2 * num3;
var result = Math.round(myTotal*100)/100

alert(myTotal);
alert(myTotal.toFixed(2));
alert(result);
</script>
```

Comment: You need to read [this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [understanding floating point variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480699/understanding-floating-point-variables)

Comment: [Why do the script engines not cache dispatch identifiers?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/why-does-jscript-have-rounding-errors.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Floating points are represented in binary, not decimal. Some decimal numbers will not be represented precisely. And unfortunately, since Javascript only has one Number class, it's not a very good tool for this job. Other languages have decent decimal libraries designed to avoid precisely this kind of error. You're going to have to either accept one-cent errors, implement a solution server-side, or work very hard to fix this.

edit: ooh! you can do 78 * 7 * 725 and then divide by 10000, or to be even more precise just put the decimal point in the right place. Basically represent the tax rate as something other than a tiny fraction. Less convenient but it'll probably take care of your multiplication errors.

Comment: Good one, I was still playing with my javascript console getting to the same point. Rather than num1, num2, etc. I found it clearer to say `quantity=78; price=7; taxrate=7.25; total = (quantity * price * taxrate) / 100;` ... I thought it clearer having the rate as a percentage and divide by 100 instead of 10,000.

Comment: Probably is. You should be fine there, because US tax rates always (afaik) fall on quarters of a percentage point, which means that if you represent them as percentages, you can represent them perfectly as floats.

Answer (score 1):

You might find the [Accounting.js](https://github.com/openexchangerates/accounting.js) library useful for this. It has an "improved" toFixed() method.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript/TypeScript have only one Number class which is not that good. I have the same problem as I am using TypeScript. I solved my problem by using [decimal.js-light](http://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js-light/#toString) library.

```
new Decimal(78).mul(7).mul(0.0725) returns as expected 39.585
```