# Javascript toFixed Not Rounding

Tags: javascript

I'm using javascript to bind to some checkboxes, and the `toFixed(2)` is not rounding up. Any ideas why it's not rounding? For instance, if the number is `859.385` it's only displaying `859.38` instead of `859.39`.

I've also read that the `toFixed` can round differently depending on which browser you are using, anyone know of a way around this so that my javascript calculations match my php calculations?

```
var standardprice = parseFloat($('#hsprice_'+this.id.split('_')[1]).val());
var price =  parseFloat($('#hprice_'+this.id.split('_')[1]).val());
var discount =  parseFloat($('#hdiscount_'+this.id.split('_')[1]).val());
var deposit =  parseFloat($('#hdeposit_'+this.id.split('_')[1]).val());

var currSprice = parseFloat($('#hTotalSprice').val());
var currPrice = parseFloat($('#hTotalPrice').val());
var currDiscount = parseFloat($('#hTotalDiscount').val());
var currDeposit = parseFloat($('#hTotalDeposit').val());

currSprice += standardprice;
currPrice += price;
currDiscount += discount;
currDeposit += deposit;

$('#lblTotalSprice').text('$'+addCommas(currSprice.toFixed(2)));
$('#lblTotalPrice').text('$'+addCommas(currPrice.toFixed(2)));
$('#lblTotalDiscount').text('$'+addCommas(currDiscount.toFixed(2)));
$('#lblTotalDeposit').text('$'+addCommas(currDeposit.toFixed(2)));

$('#hTotalSprice').val(currSprice.toFixed(2));
$('#hTotalPrice').val(currPrice.toFixed(2));
$('#hTotalDiscount').val(currDiscount.toFixed(2));
$('#hTotalDeposit').val(currDeposit.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: Since 0.5 is exactly halfway between 0 and 1 and rounding up is only a convention, I wonder how important it really is to guarantee a specific result. On the other hand, in order to test your code, you need predictable results and testing is important, so that's a good reason.

Comment: Here's a hint as to why the rounding of `.toFixed` can seem unintuitive: `(0.1).toFixed(20)` . (Note that IE's implementation gives the "intuitive" result, while other browsers give the standards-compliant value.)

Comment: My answer for similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37751946/2261514

Comment: `Intl.NumberFormat` rounding works. It could be used wherever num.isFixed() is used. see [Formatting a number with exactly two decimals in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/formatting-a-number-with-exactly-two-decimals-in-javascript/1726662#1726662)

Comment: @Noyo sorry for 9 year necro but I don't know that `.toFixed(20)` is a sensible thing to ever do with IEEE754 doubles. Because, 53 bits of mantissa can only give you `log_10(2^53)` = 15.95 base-10 digits worth of precision to work with... Going beyond that is going to have the number renderer (in this case `.toFixed`) to somewhat hallucinate digits. `0.1.toFixed(20)` = `'0.10000000000000000555'` may be a "correct" decimal representation of whatever the closest double value to 0.1 is, and the same might be said for `0.1.toFixed(30)`: `0.100000000000000005551115123126` but this is not useful.

Comment: Hi @StevenLu, it's just an illustrative example (though maybe a bit impractical) to demonstrate how the function's behavior can be unintuitive and probably not the right tool for the OP's use case. You can read a more thorough explanation in my even older answer to a related question here (and others' answers): https://stackoverflow.com/a/27299513/357774
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 46):

> I have yet to find a number that toFixed10 does wrong. Can anybody else?

Thanks to `blg` and [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23204425/1532548) which pointed me to Mozilla's [toFixed10()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round$revision/1383484) method.

Using that I came up with this short one liner, which indeed covers all cases mentioned here...

```
function toFixed( num, precision ) {
    return (+(Math.round(+(num + 'e' + precision)) + 'e' + -precision)).toFixed(precision);
}
```

Comment: What/where is toFixed10? Please add a link to it?

Comment: Number 0.0000001 or less results in NaN

Comment: @ledlogic `toFixed10` looks like it was added by blg, it just calls `round10` and then `toFixed`.

Comment: Nope, this is still imprecise, `toFixed(89.684449, 2)` should be `89.69`, but is `89.68`.

Comment: This doesn't handle double rounding. This is answer works https://stackoverflow.com/a/43998255/304894

Comment: @mrts toFixed(89.684449, 2) is correctly 89.68, it would be only 69 if it was 89.685<any other irrelevant digits>

Comment: On `toFixed(0.000000015, 8)` get NaN. For correct answer 0.00000002 I use this function `function round(v,d){return parseFloat(Math.round(v.toFixed(d+1)+'e'+d)+'e-'+d)};`

Comment: That toFixed10() link is broken, not archived, and [the history for that wiki page](https://github.com/mdn/content/commits/main/files/en-us/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/math/round) (now hosted on Github) doesn't go far back enough. It looks like the [JSFiddle associated with that other answer](https://jsfiddle.net/cCX5y/2/) is still up though.

Comment: @Codler Funnily enough the second comment on that answer points out a failing case.

Answer (score 28):

I made this to use in all financial data as a best rounding function. You can test it on all problematic numbers. Javascript allows some sort of precision, so I used it to make almost every number be rounded as expected.

```
function roundTo(n, digits) {
        if (digits === undefined) {
            digits = 0;
        }

        var multiplicator = Math.pow(10, digits);
        n = parseFloat((n * multiplicator).toFixed(11));
        return Math.round(n) / multiplicator;
    }
```

Comment: Umm the comment is misleading, roundTo(89.684449, 2) shouldn't be 89.69, and is legitimately 89.68.

Answer (score 26):

In Chrome, `toFixed()` rounds:

```
859.385 ==> 859.38
859.386 ==> 859.39
```

When I look at [the ECMAScript 5th edition specification for `.toFixed()`](http://www.ecmascript.org/docs/tc39-2009-043.pdf) (section 15.7.4.5), I do not see it explicitly describe rounding though it does describe something fairly obtusely that may be what Chrome has implemented.

It appears to me that if you want to control it with explicit rounding, then you should probably use the oft-suggested workaround of:

```
var roundedNum = (Math.round( num * 100 ) / 100).toFixed(2);
```

This will guarantee that you get predictable rounding like you are used to.

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/kvpgE/

Comment: It'll **normally** guarantee that you get predictable rounding.  

However, as mentioned [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406494/javascript-multiplying-incorrectly-causing-incorrect-rounding) the way javascript handles decimals can't really be trusted.  

Just try 35.855*100 in the Chrome console...  
I know, I was shocked too!  
This will mean that  
`(Math.round( 35.855 * 100 ) / 100).toFixed(2) == 35.85`  
rather than 35.86.  

See that other answer for tips...

Comment: @mattbilson This is standard IEEE floating point and doesn't mean JavaScript is untrustworthy in this regard. Floating point numbers just aren't the real numbers (mathematical sense) but are entirely predictable.

Comment: This is not a perfect answer. If you input 1.005, you'll get 1.00 but it should be 1.01.

Comment: @foxiris - Yep, due to the wonders of floating point, `1.005 * 100` comes out to be `100.49999999999999` which derails the rest of the algorithm.

Answer (score 22):

Since in javascripts' toFixed-function, the floating point number`5` does not belong to the upper half of an integer, the given number is rounded down if you have numbers like these:

`859.385.toFixed(2) // results in 859.38`

for a matter of fact you might append trailing floating point numbers (except zero) like here:

`859.3851.toFixed(2) // results in 859.39`

Therefore developers tend to add numbers like `0.00000000001` in order for it to be rounded appropriate and to not accidentally change the value of the number.

So I came up with a function which adds such a number depending on how many digits you want your floating point number to be fixed:

```
    // both parameters can be string or number
    function toFixed(number, decimals) {
        const x = Math.pow(10, Number(decimals) + 2);
        return (Number(number) + (1 / x)).toFixed(decimals)
    }
    toFixed(859.385, 2) //results in 859.39
    toFixed(859.3844, 2) //results in 859.38
```

Comment: Best answer I could find! Easy code to read and it even handle double rounding!

Comment: `toFixed(859.3844, 2)` gives `859.39`, but should be `859.38`

Comment: toFixed(.004, 2);  == .00  ... not .01

Comment: Usually we know what precision we want to round to.  Let's say we want num.toFixed(2).  Then adding .0001 to num gets the right answer from toFixed.  While a general function is fine, it seems to me to be a bit of overkill, unless the number of desired digits is a variable -- an unlikely circumstance.

Comment: The idea is good but there is a mistake. The added fraction is too big and because of it even `0.0046` is rounded to `0.01`. Changing the intermediate line to `var x = Math.pow(10, Number(decimals) + 2);` helps resolving the issue

Answer (score 17):

`toFixed` was never *rounding* nor meant for it.

It barely converts a floating point (exponent, mantissa) into a fixed-point (integer, decimals) (see [definition](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-number.prototype.tofixed)).

While doing this, it might look as if it's rounding, because the *rounded* number is the closest approximation to the original floating-point representation.

Sadly, it is widely spread that `toFixed` can be used for rounding... well no it cannot, even the name suggests has nothing to do with it.

If you need rounding plus the `toFixed` padding:

```js
function round(num, precision) {
  var base = 10 ** precision;
  return (Math.round(num * base) / base).toFixed(precision);
}
```

Comment: Someone get this guy a cookie. This is the proper way to round currency.

Comment: `round(148.325, 2)` gives `'148.32'` because `148.325 * 100` is `14832.499999999998`

Answer (score 10):

Another good number to try along with 35.855 is 1.005

I don't think Robert Messerle's solution handles 1.005

The rounding decimal example here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round$revision/1383484#Decimal_rounding converts numbers to exponential notation and seems to get better results.

I created a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/cCX5y/2/ that  demos the native, Robert Messerle  example above (called `toFixedB`) and the one from Mozilla docs (called `toFixed10`).

I have yet to find a number that toFixed10 does wrong. Can anybody else?

Comment: Good fiddle and link.  I added user2823670's one-liner: http://jsfiddle.net/cCX5y/3/

Comment: Looks like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5535472/573634) also works and doesn't involve all the extra code.

Comment: All of them are imprecise, `toFixed10(89.684449, 2)` and others should be `89.69`, but is `89.68`.

Comment: I think you are double rounding. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding). Any number such as 1.2345 will round to 1.23 not 1.24

Answer (score 9):

```
function roundup(num,dec){
    dec= dec || 0;
    var  s=String(num);
    if(num%1)s= s.replace(/5$/, '6');
    return Number((+s).toFixed(dec));
 }

 var n= 35.855
 roundup(n,2)
```

/*  returned value: (Number)
35.86
*/

Comment: Try it with `35.855`.

Comment: This is the only solution I've seen that will round predictably.

Comment: The only problem is, it doesn't work if one of the decimals is 5 and the number of decimals to round to is higher than the position of that 5, e.g. roundup(70.5, 2). This could easily be improved by changing the regular expression in the replace statement, to something like: s.replace(/(\d{n})5/, '$16'), with n being equal to the dec paraemter. We only need to change the 5 in the n+1th position behind the decimal point, when rounding to n decimals, am I right?

Answer (score 9):

`toFixed()` works correctly!
The problem is, that 859.385 has no representation as float at a computer. It is scanned as nearest possible value = 859.384999999999991. And rounding this value to 2 digits is 859.38 and not 859.39.

This is the reasons, that many programming languages (especially old for commerce, e.g. COBOL) support BCD numbers (binary coded decimals), where each digit is coded by itself into 4 bits (like hex without using A-F).

A general solution for prices: Calculate in cent/penny and print NUMBER/100.

A note to other solutions (functions provided here):
They may help for some numbers, but mostly fail for e.g. 859.38499999.

Comment: I put link here for more information [see](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-number.prototype.tofixed)

Comment: @Let'sApp Your helper function works incorrectly. And if you read my answer, you can see, that the problem is scanning the number `859.385` and not function `toFixed()`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `Math.round()` to round the number. If you want to round to a specific decimal point you can employ a little math:

```
var result=Math.round(original*100)/100
```

Comment: Note that this is unreliable. Try it with `35.855`, for instance, and you'll end up with `35.85` (not `35.86`).

Comment: noe that this was just an example. insert for the `100` `Math.pow(10, decimalpoint)` where `decimalpoint` is the numbers of floating point digits you want to round your number

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this same problem today, and even trying suggestions in other answers I found that I still did not receive the result I expected. Finally, as I'm using AngularJS for my current project when running into this, I figured I check if AngularJS has already solved the same kind of problem before and indeed they had. Here's the solution they use and it works perfectly for me:

```
function toFixed(number, fractionSize) {
    return +(Math.round(+(number.toString() + 'e' + fractionSize)).toString() + 'e' + -fractionSize);
}
```

Found here: [AngularJS filters.js source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filters.js#L179)

Comment: This is identical to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23560569/1532548) except AngularJS doesn't have the trailing `.toFixed()`

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking to get **a number as output**, then consider the `Math.round()` technique in other answers.

But if you want to get **a string as output, for presentation to a human**, then often [`n.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) is more helpful than `n.toFixed()`.

Why? Because it will also add commas or periods to the head of large numbers, which humans use to read. For example:

```
var n = 1859.385

n.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2})

// Produces  1,859.39  in USA (locale en-US)
// Produces  1 859,39  in France (locale fr-FR)
// Produces  1.859,39  in Germany (locale de-DE)
```

The spec says that when passing `undefined` as the first argument, the user's own locale will be used (as specified by the OS).  Unfortunately, as the linked documentation shows, Mozilla uses the en-US locale in this situation, but it may comply with the spec in future.

Comment: It works also for negative numbers that is good

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled upon this wondering why `Number.toFixed` was behaving strangely. I see that the native function is unreliable, which is unfortunate. Looking over the answers out of curiosity, I see most* of them don't behave properly with the number `35.855` as T.J. Crowder graciously commented on every one.

Maybe this will answer your question.

```
function toFixed(n,precision) {
    var match=RegExp("(\\d+\\.\\d{1,"+precision+"})(\\d)?").exec(n);
    if(match===null||match[2]===undefined) {
        return n.toFixed(precision);
        }
    if(match[2]>=5) {
        return (Number(match[1])+Math.pow(10,-precision)).toFixed(precision);
        }
    return match[1];
    }
```

The regex splits your number into an array of strings such as in `toFixed(35.855,2)`: `["35.855", "35.85", "5"]`. If the last number (after the precision cutoff) is `>=5`, add `Math.pow(10, -precision)` to the trimmed number. This will add `.01` if you're cutting off at 2 decimals, `.002` at 3, so on and so forth.

I don't know if this is foolproof, since it still performs decimal math on floats which can be unpredictable. I can say it rounds `35.855` up to `35.86`.

Answer (score 4):

Joy twindle answer here should be the best answer instead of the so many hack arounds.

```
   x = 1859.385;
   x = x.toFixed(2);
   alert(x);
```

gives a wrong rounding off ie 1859.38 instead of 1859.39

```
 x = 1859.385;
 x = x.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2});
 alert(x);
```

gives a correct rounding off 1,859.39

The only problem is the result returned is a string with thousand comma separator and so cannot be used for calculations. Using a regex i got from stack overflow to remove the comma the final result is

```
 x = 1859.385;
 x = x.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2});
 x=x.replace(/\,/g,'');
 alert(x);
```

that now returns 1859.39 and can be used for calculations.
The value before regex ie 1,859.39 can be used for html display while the un-formatted value 1859.39 can be used for calculations.

Comment: The first argument is for the  locale string. Ex. 'en-US'

Comment: @webs The "comma" is a "thousands separator" and differs if you do not specify a locale as first argument like "en-US". So this solution will only work in countries where they use a comma as thousands separator. Instead of using your regex you can just turn this off with the option `useGrouping: false`. E.g.: `.toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2, useGrouping: false})`

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but why not doing something like this:

```
let TruncatedValueInString = ThenNumberYouWantToTruncate.toFixed(decPlaces + 1).slice(0, -1);
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Note: You may only need this .toFixed() solution for handling very large numbers

#### Other posted solutions work well for standard numbers (below 1e21)

If you want to **handle very large numbers and very small fractions** with `toFixed` with correct rounding and without loss of accuracy and without having to use libraries and with a self-contained function, one possible effective solution is to make use of the `BigInt` to avoid loss of accuracy due to internal javascript rounding.

The function below `toFixed(number, [digits])` does this.

Just pass the large number as a string with the required number of rounding digits. Numbers will be rounded properly.

The concept is the common way to split the number into the whole part and the decimal part but use `BigInt()` to hold these 2 parts. Thereafter, round and process as necessary for both positive and negative numbers without using any of the javascript `Math` or number functions to avoid loss of accuracy.

As a bonus for very special cases where the number is in a very large 'e' notation, I have added the `eToNumber()` function I have posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66072001/11606728 to do that as an inline process. This may be removed if you want to maintain shortcode and do not bother about such numbers. [comments are provided in the code to remove it].

I have included various test cases to test the different possibilities (some of which are a bit odd but nevertheless do occur).

This idea can be taken further for improvement.

Hope it is useful.

```js
/****************************************************************************
* @function    : toFixed(number, [digits])
* @purpose     : Emulate toFixed() for large numbers and
                 large fractional numbers with correct rounding
                 by using the BigInt() built-in Object.
* @version     : 1.01
* @author      : Mohsen Alyafei
* @date        : 03 February 2021
* @param       : {number} [numeric or string] pass large numbers as a string
* @param       : {number} [optional digits]
*              : The number of digits to appear after the decimal point;
*              : this may be a value from 0 and above unlimited.
*              : If this argument is omitted or is negative, it is treated as 0.
*              : Handles large 'e' notation number using the eToNumber() function.digits
*              : See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66072001/11606728
* @returns     : A string representing the given number using fixed-point notation.
****************************************************************************/

function toFixed(num,digits) {
    if (!num && num!==0) return "Cannot read property of null or undefined"; // Can change it to throw Error
    digits<0 && (digits=0);
    digits=digits||0;
    num=eToNumber(num); // Delete this line and function below if larage 'e' notation number are not required
    let wh = (num+="").split((.1).toLocaleString().substr(1,1)), f = wh[1];
    wh = wh[0];
    let fr = (f=f||"0").substr(0,digits), fn = BigInt(fr), w = BigInt(wh), fl = (""+fn).length,
        lZeros = fr.length-fl, minus = wh[0]=="-", inc = (wh<0 || minus) ? BigInt(-1):BigInt(1);
    f[digits]>=5 && (fn+=BigInt(1));
    (fn+="").length > fl && (lZeros-=1);
    lZeros >=0 ? lZeros="0".repeat(lZeros):(fn=fn.substring(1), lZeros="",
               (fn ? w +=inc : ((f[digits]>=5) && (w+=inc))));
    fn = lZeros + fn; L = digits-fn.length;
    L && (fn+="0".repeat(L)); w==0 && minus && (w="-"+w);
    return w+(fn?".":"")+fn;
    }

    //---------------------- Extra Function if needed --------------------------------
    // Delete this function if large 'e' notation number are not required
    // Convert very large 'e' numbers to plain string numbers.
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function eToNumber(num) {
        let sign="";
        (num+="").charAt(0)=="-" && (num=num.substring(1),sign ="-");
        let arr = num.split(/[e]/ig); if (arr.length<2) return sign+num;
        let dot=(.1).toLocaleString().substr(1,1), n = arr[0], exp = +arr[1];
        let w = (n=n.replace(/^0+/,'')).replace(dot,''),
          pos = n.split(dot)[1]? n.indexOf(dot)+exp : w.length+exp,
            L = pos-w.length,s=""+BigInt(w);
         w = exp>=0 ? (L>=0 ? s+"0".repeat(L):r()): (pos<=0 ? "0"+dot+"0".repeat(Math.abs(pos))+s:r());
        if (!+w) w=0; return sign+w;
        function r(){return w.replace(new RegExp(`^(.{${pos}})(.)`),`$1${dot}$2`)}}

//================================================
//             Test Cases
//================================================
let r=0; // test tracker
r |= test(35.855,2,"35.86");
r |= test(12.00000015,2,"12.00");
r |= test(35.855,5,"35.85500");
r |= test(35.855,4,"35.8550");
r |= test(1.135,2,"1.14");
r |= test(1.135,3,"1.135");
r |= test(1.135,4,"1.1350");
r |= test(1.135,8,"1.13500000");
r |= test(0.1545,3,"0.155");
r |= test(89.684449,2,"89.68");
r |= test("0.0000001",2,"0.00");
r |= test("0.9993360575508052",3,"0.999");
r |= test("0.999336057550805244545454545",29,"0.99933605755080524454545454500");
r |= test("1.0020739645577939",3,"1.002");
r |= test(0.999,0,"1");
r |= test(0.999,1,"1.0");
r |= test(0.999,2,"1.00");
r |= test(0.975,0,"1");
r |= test(0.975,1,"1.0");
r |= test(0.975,2,"0.98");
r |= test(2.145,2,"2.15");
r |= test(2.135,2,"2.14");
r |= test(2.34,1,"2.3");
r |= test(2.35,1,"2.4");
r |= test("0.0000001",2,"0.00");
r |= test("0.0000001",7,"0.0000001");
r |= test("0.0000001",8,"0.00000010");
r |= test("0.00000015",2,"0.00");
if (r==0) console.log("Tests 01. Standard fractional numbers passed");
//================================================
r=0; // test tracker
r |= test("1234567890123456789444.99",5,"1234567890123456789444.99000");
r |= test("1234567890123456789444.1445",3,"1234567890123456789444.145");
r |= test("1234567890123456789444.14451445144514451745",19,"1234567890123456789444.1445144514451445175");
if (r==0) console.log("Tests 02. Large fractional numbers passed");
//================================================
r=0; // test tracker
r |= test(100,2,"100.00");
r |= test(0,5,"0.00000");
if (r==0) console.log("Tests 03. Non-fractional numbers passed");
//================================================
r=0; // test tracker
r |= test(12345.6789,null,"12346");
r |= test(2.1234,null,"2");
r |= test(12345.6789,undefined,"12346");
r |= test(2.1234,undefined,"2");
r |= test(12345.6789,"","12346");
r |= test(0.1234,"","0");
r |= test(2.1234,"","2");
if (r==0) console.log("Tests 04. Undefined, Null, and Empty Digits passed");
//================================================
r=0; // test tracker
r |= test(1.1155,2,"1.12");
r |= test(1.255,2,"1.26");
r |= test(1.265,2,"1.27");
r |= test(1.275,2,"1.28");
r |= test(1.285,2,"1.29");
r |= test(1.295,2,"1.30");
r |= test(2.05,1,"2.1");
r |= test(2.15,1,"2.2");
r |= test(2.55,1,"2.6");
r |= test(2.65,1,"2.7");
r |= test(2.215,2,"2.22");
r |= test(2.315,2,"2.32");
r |= test(2.715,2,"2.72");
r |= test(2.815,2,"2.82");
r |= test(2.005,2,"2.01");
r |= test(2.105,2,"2.11");
r |= test(2.405,2,"2.41");
r |= test(2.505,2,"2.51");
r |= test(2.605,2,"2.61");
r |= test(2.905,2,"2.91");
r |= test(0.00155,4,"0.0016");
r |= test(2.55,1,"2.6");
r |= test(-2.35,1,"-2.4");
if (r==0) console.log("Tests 05. Correct rounding passed");
//================================================
r=0; // test tracker
r |= test(-1.125,2,"-1.13");
r |= test(-1.15,1,"-1.2");
r |= test(-1.15,1,"-1.2");
r |= test(-1.45,1,"-1.5");
r |= test(-1.65,1,"-1.7");
r |= test(-1.95,1,"-2.0");
r |= test(-2.34,1,"-2.3");
r |= test("-0.024641163062896567",3,"-0.025");
r |= test("-0.024641163062896567",16,"-0.0246411630628966");
r |= test("0.024641163062896567",16, "0.0246411630628966");
r |= test("-0.0246411630628965",16,"-0.0246411630628965");
if (r==0) console.log("Tests 06. Negative numbers rounding passed");
//================================================
r=0; // test tracker
r |= test(.135,2,"0.14");    // without whole part
r |= test(-.135,2,"-0.14");
r |= test("+35.855",2,"35.86");
r |= test("0.0",2,"0.00");
r |= test("-0",2,"-0.00");       //minus 0
r |= test("-0.0",5,"-0.00000");  // minus 0
r |= test("",5,"Cannot read property of null or undefined");        // empty string
r |= test(null,5,"Cannot read property of null or undefined");      //null
r |= test(undefined,5,"Cannot read property of null or undefined"); // undefined
if (r==0) console.log("Tests 07. Special test cases passed");
//================================================
r=0; // test tracker
r |= test(1.1234e1,2,"11.23");      //11.234
r |= test(1.12e2,2,"112.00");       //112
r |= test(-1.1234e2,2,"-112.34");   // -112.34
r |= test(-1.1234e2,4,"-112.3400"); // -112.34
r |= test(-1.1235e2,2,"-112.35");   // -112.35
r |= test(-1.1235e2,1,"-112.4");    // -112.4
if (r==0) console.log("Tests 08. Standard e notation numbers passed");
//================================================

r=0; // test tracker
r |= test("123456789123456789.111122223333444455556666777788889999e+10",16,"1234567891234567891111222233.3344445555666678");
r |= test("1.1235678944556677e2",20,"112.35678944556677000000");
r |= test("99.1235678944556677e2",20,"9912.35678944556677000000");
if (r==0) console.log("Tests 09. Large e notation numbers passed");
//================================================

if (r==0) console.log(`${"-".repeat(22)}\nAll Test Cases Passed.\n${"-".repeat(22)}`);

//================================================
//             Test function
//================================================
function test(n1,n2,should) {
let result = toFixed(n1,n2);
if (result !== should) {console.log(`Output   : ${result}\nShould be: ${should}`);return 1;}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

this might help

```
    tofix2Decimals=function(float){
        if(parseInt(float)==float)return float.toFixed(2);
        $decimals=/\.(\d+)/.exec(float)[1].length;
        $decimals=$decimals>=2?$decimals+1:3;
        float+=Math.pow(10,-$decimals);
        return float.toFixed(2);
    }
```

Comment: An *explanation* might help.

Comment: A fine and fancy trip to the obfuscating rink.  Ugh.

Answer (score 3):

The `toFixed()` method in JavaScript does not follow the standard rounding rules for numbers ending in `.5`. It uses the "round half up" strategy, which means it rounds up when the next digit is 5 or greater.

If you need to round numbers ending in `.5` in a more consistent way, you can create a custom rounding function. Here's an example:

```
function roundNumber(number, decimalPlaces) {
  const factor = 10 ** decimalPlaces;
  return Math.round(number * factor) / factor;
}

const number = 3.145;
const roundedNumber = roundNumber(number, 2);

console.log(roundedNumber); // Output: 3.15
```

Alternatively, you can use [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) method to achieve this. Here's another example:

```
const number = 3.145;
const locales = window.navigator.language;
const options = { maximumFractionDigits: 2 };
const roundedNumber = Number(number.toLocaleString(locales, options));

console.log(roundedNumber); // Output: 3.15
```

Comment: This does not work if e.g. `window.navigator.language` is `de-DE`, because this locale uses a `,` instead of `.` as decimal separator, but the `Number()` constructor requires the decimal separator to be a `.`. You should make the locale constant, e.g. `"en-US"`.

Answer (score 2):

I have got proper solution from [Lam Wei Li](https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round$revision/1383484)

```
function round(number, precision) {
  var shift = function (number, exponent) {
    var numArray = ("" + number).split("e");
    return +(numArray[0] + "e" + (numArray[1] ? (+numArray[1] + exponent) : exponent));
  };
  return shift(Math.round(shift(number, +precision)), -precision);
}
```

Test Result

```
round(1.050, 1); // expected 1.1 , result 1.1  (correct)
round(1.005, 2); // expected 1.01, result 1.01 (correct)

round(3456.3456,  3); // 3456.346
round(3456.3456,  2); // 3456.35
round(3456.3456,  1); // 3456.3
round(3456.3456,  0); // 3456
round(3456.3456, -1); // 3460
round(3456.3456, -2); // 3500
round(3456.3456, -3); // 3000

round(undefined, 1        ); // NaN
round(null     , 1        ); // NaN
round("a"      , 1        ); // NaN
round(1        , null     ); // NaN
round(1        , undefined); // NaN
round(1        , "a"      ); // NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted something concise and accurate with a good combination of readable and speed. After reading all the answers to this question, and [this particularly helpful answer in a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48764436/25197), this is my solution.

```js
const round = (numberToRound, digits = 0, toFixed = false) => {
  const precision = 10 ** digits;
  const n = numberToRound * precision * (1 + Number.EPSILON);
  const roundedNumber = Math.round(n) / precision;
  return toFixed ? roundedNumber.toFixed(digits) : roundedNumber;
};

// rounding by half
console.log(round(0.5));
console.log(round(-0.5));

// fixed decimals
console.log(round(0.5, 2), '( Type:',typeof round(0.5, 2), ')');
console.log(round(0.5, 2, true), '( Type:',typeof round(0.5, 2, true), ')');
console.log(round(-0.5, 2), '( Type:',typeof round(-0.5, 2), ')');
console.log(round(-0.5, 2, true), '( Type:',typeof round(-0.5, 2, true), ')');

// edge cases
console.log(round(1.005, 2) === 1.01);
console.log(round(-1.005, 2) === -1.01);
console.log(round(39.425, 2) === 39.43);
console.log(round(-39.425, 2) === -39.43);
console.log(round(1234.00000254495, 10) === 1234.000002545);
console.log(round(-1234.00000254495, 10) === -1234.0000025449);

// edge cases from other answer's comments.
console.log(round(859.385, 2));
console.log(round(859.3844, 2));
console.log(round(0.000000015, 8))
console.log(round(35.855, 2));
```

I don't love `toFixed` as a boolean parameter but it works for now.

Answer (score 2):

```
function toFixed(num, decimals) {
    return (Math.round((num + Number.EPSILON) * Math.pow(10, decimals)) / Math.pow(10, decimals)).toFixed(decimals)
}
```

I've found a valid answer here -> [Round to at most 2 decimal places (only if necessary)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11832950)

```
Math.round((num + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100
```

You have to add `Number.EPSILON` to the rounded number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, including 3 features.

1. **Correct round up.**
2. **Display only in number.** (Preventing Scientific Notation)
3. **Removes trailing zeros.**

I combined @user2823670's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23560569/4729203) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61281355/4729203) together.

```
var roundUp = function(num, precision) {
    // Return '' if num is empty string
    if (typeof num === 'string' && !num) return '';

    // Remove exponential notation
    num = toPlainString(num);

    // Fixed round up
    var result = +((+(Math.round(+(num + 'e' + precision)) + 'e' + -precision)).toFixed(precision));

    // Remove exponential notation (once again)
    result = toPlainString(result);

    return result;
};

var toPlainString = function(num) {
    return ('' + num).replace(/(-?)(\d*)\.?(\d+)e([+-]\d+)/,
        function(a, b, c, d, e) {
            return e < 0
                ? b + '0.' + Array(1 - e - c.length).join(0) + c + d
                : b + c + d + Array(e - d.length + 1).join(0);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: The second function `toPlainString` does not work properly. Still, the following numbers do not convert 1e-7 it should be 0.0000001 but gives 0.00000001 i.e. with one more zero inserted. Similarly for 1e-8, 1e-9 and higher.

Comment: change the regex to the following `replace(/(-?)(\d*)\.?(\d*)e([+-]\d+)/` to get it working.

Comment: An alternative solution for converting 'e' notation numbers (keeping accuracy) for large numbers and large fractions above 1^21 can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66072001/11606728

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me - "hackish"

```
function customTofix(value, precision) {
    let decimalVal = 0;
    
    if (value !== null) {
        let appendValue = (((value - Math.floor(value)) !== 0) ? (precision <= (value.toString().split(".")[1].length || 0)) ? '1' : '' : '');
        decimalVal = parseFloat(value.toString() + appendValue).toFixed(precision)
    }

    return decimalVal
}
```

Comment: .toFixed() has a bug.  My answer below provides a helper function to fix the problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015027/javascript-tofixed-not-rounding/77596425#77596425

Answer (score 0):

My workout:

> For me, This was enough to include in common javascript like helpers.js

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-extend-native
Number.prototype.toFixed = function (fractionDigits) {
    var precisionTens = Math.pow(10, fractionDigits || 0);
    return (Math.round(Number(this) * precisionTens) / precisionTens);
}
```

This will overwrite the native javascript `toFixed()` prototype function.

Answer (score 0):

I spent way too long on this.

```
export function parseFloat<TDefault>(nbr: string | number, defaultValue: TDefault): number | TDefault
export function parseFloat(nbr: string | number): number | null
export function parseFloat(nbr: string | number, defaultValue: any = null): number | null {
    if(nbr == null || nbr === '') return defaultValue
    const val = globalThis.parseFloat(nbr as string)
    return Number.isFinite(val) ? val : defaultValue
}

export function fullWide(n: number|string):string {
    return parseFloat(n,0).toLocaleString('en-US', {useGrouping: false, maximumFractionDigits: 20})
}

export function round(value: string | number, decimalDigits = 0): number {
    return +(`${Math.round(+(`${fullWide(value)}e${decimalDigits}`))}e${-decimalDigits}`)
}
```

Passes all these tests:

```
test('round', () => {
    expect(round(1.2345, 0)).toBe(1)
    expect(round(1.2345, 1)).toBe(1.2)
    expect(round(1.2345, 2)).toBe(1.23)
    expect(round(1.2345, 3)).toBe(1.235)
    expect(round(1.2345, 4)).toBe(1.2345)
    expect(round(3.141592653589793, 15)).toBe(3.141592653589793)
    expect(round(3.141592653589793, 13)).toBe(3.1415926535898)
    expect(round(12.345, -1)).toBe(10)
    expect(round(4_500, -3)).toBe(5000)
    expect(round(89.684449, 2)).toBe(89.68)
    expect(round(89.685, 2)).toBe(89.69)
    expect(round(0.000000015, 8)).toBe(0.00000002)
    expect(round(1e-20, 20)).toBe(1e-20)
    expect(round(1.5e-19, 20)).toBe(0.00000000000000000015)
    expect(round(1.5e-19, 19)).toBe(0.0000000000000000002)
    expect(round('1.5e-19', 19)).toBe(0.0000000000000000002)
    expect(round('bacon', 19)).toBe(0)
})
```

Comment: @Let'sApp I didn't use `toFixed` in my answer. Stop spamming this under everyone's answer to promote your own answer.

Comment: I don't see it as span since it works and can help others.  But, you're entitled to your opinion.

Answer (score -3):

UPDATED: This post will ANSWER the question and provide a HELPER FUNCTION for toFixed() since toFixed() is still broken, years later, in all major browsers.

The problem is verified to be the number 5. toFixed() doesn't round up when it sees the number 5 in the folowing position you want to round.

This HELPER FUNCTION will take in a number and a postion. The position is the same as you would use it with toFixed().

For example, if you need JS to round the cents for a number like $100.695 to $100.70. You would provide the number (100.695) and the position you want to round to (2).

In the example above, the function will split the number at the decimal point. Then it will look at the third digit to the right of the decimal. If the digit is a 5 then it will simply add .001 to the number and then you can call toFixed(2) and get the desired output. You can also use this for any position you want to round to.

See my codepen at https://codepen.io/letsapp/pen/MWREXaj

There is some logic built in for error handling.

```js
validate_to_fixed.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        const original_value = document.getElementById('input_value').value
        const position = document.getElementById('position').value
        const new_value = validateToFixed(original_value, position)
        console.log(new_value)
        output_value.value = new_value
      })
      function validateToFixed(number, position) {
        const original_number = number
        number = number.toString()
        let split = number.split('.')
        console.log(split)
        if (!split[1]) {
          number = Number(number).toFixed(position)
          console.log(number)
          return number
        }
        if (split[1].charAt(position) === '5') {
          let adder = [0, '.']
          for (let index = 0; index < position; index++) {
            adder.push(parseInt(0))
          }
          adder.push(1)
          adder = Number(adder.join(''))
          number = (Number(number) + adder).toFixed(position)
          console.log('original is ' + original_number)
                    console.log(`${adder} was added to ${original_number} and (${Number(original_number) + Number(adder)}).toFixed(${position}) was called resulting in ${number}`)
          return number
        } else {
          return (number = Number(number).toFixed(position))
        }
      }
```

```css
.container {
        width: 500px;
        margin-inline: auto;
        margin-top: 20px;
        /* border: 1px solid lightgray; */
      }
      form {
        width: 150px;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
      }
      input {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }

      button {
        margin-top: 20px;
        width: 75px;
        height: 30px;
      }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <form>
        <label for="input_value">
          Original Number
          <input id="input_value" type="number" value="100.695" />
        </label>
        <label for="position">
          Position to round
          <input id="position" type="number" value="2" />
        </label>
        <label for="output_value">
          New Value
          <input id="output_value" type="number" disabled />
        </label>
        <button id="validate_to_fixed">Round</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: The correct result of `(100.695).toFixed()` is `100.69`!! The issue is, that number `00.695` does not exists and is rounded in a first step to the nearest possible number, here to `100.694999999999993` (verify with `(100.695).toPrecision(18)`). And this number is then rounded by `toFixed()`.

Comment: `validateToFixed(100.69499999999999, 2)` returns the wrong value `100.70`.

Comment: @Let'sApp `validateToFixed(0.000000015, 8)` also incorrectly returns `0.00000001`, but it should be `0.00000002`.

Comment: @Wiimm how is 100.70 incorrect?  Maybe you can help me understand.  If I am say writing a quoting app and the total comes out to be $100.695, wouldn't you want that number to round up to $100.70?

Comment: @Let'sApp I tested the value `100.69499999999999`, that must be rounded down.

Comment: @Toxiro I had some conditional logic that only worked for my use case.  So, I updated the helper function based on your tests.  Thank you for your input.  I made some basic changes to the conditional logic and now it works for your use cases as well.  I will update my post with the new logic.

Comment: @Let'sApp `validateToFixed(0.000000015, 8)` still incorrectly returns 0.00000001, but it should be 0.00000002.

Comment: @Toxiro it works perfectly for me using the values you gave me.  Check out my codepen.  I used the last version in prod for my use case, but this version is even better since now it will work for any position.  Thanks for your help by pointing out the previous issue!  Here si the codepen https://codepen.io/letsapp/pen/MWREXaj

Comment: @Let'sApp Your `codepen.io` link works, but the function `validateToFixed` in the answer you posted is still wrong.

Comment: @Toxiro Not sure why.  I just updated the post and copied and pasted right from vscode into stack.  It should work.  Maybe you can try again and let me know?

Comment: @Let'sApp Your function cannot work, because you are using `number.toString()` and for example `0.000000015.toString()` is `1.5e-8` and not `0.000000015` (just paste it in your browsers console to verify). The only reason why your example works, is, because you are using it with a html form and this form returns `0.000000015` directly as string and not as number. So your `toString` function is useless and your `validateToFixed` function only works for strings, but we need a function for numbers. The author of the question intentionally used `parseFloat` before using `toFixed`.

Comment: @Let'sApp One tip for the future. If you want upvotes for whatever reason (you cannot buy anything from it): don't spam each question's comment section, even not when your 100% certain. People don't like that. You might be still young and sometimes it's ok to overestimate yourself, but try not to say something like ".toFixed has a bug", if you do not know exactly what it is doing. `toFixed` is defined in the EcmaScript standard: https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-number.prototype.tofixed and works as expected with IEEE-754 double-precision float 64 numbers.

Comment: You literally posted a comment pointing to your answer under every single answer in this question. Please don't do that.