# Fomating decimal values JavaScript

Tags: javascript, format, decimal

I need format a decimal number on JavaScript, my number are returning 100.000 but I want 100,00.

```
var val = 100.0000;
console.log(val);
// do something
console.log(val);
```

> what I get: 100.0000
>   what I expected: 100,00

what I need to do for made this?

Comment: Do you want 100,00 or 100.00 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript math, round to two decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762768/javascript-math-round-to-two-decimal-places)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
parseFloat(val).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
```

See in action: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bs9va6es/)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the need. I suggest to have a look to the formatting methods of [`Number.prototype.toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

```js
var val = 100.0000;
document.write(val.toLocaleString('de-DE', { maximumFractionDigits: 2, minimumFractionDigits: 2}));
```