# Round converted value from html form to nearest hundredth using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html form that contains an `input` field for a person's weight.  The input field type is a textbox and allows a user to enter their weight.  There is a dropdown next to it that allows for the user to convert their weight from pounds to kilograms.  When the user changes the weight unit, the value in the textbox is converted.

So when a user enters their weight in pounds and then selects kilograms from the dropdown, **I want this value to be rounded to the nearest hundredth**.

**HTML:**

```
         <label> Weight:</label>
                <input type="text" id="weight_value" />
                    <select id="weight_unit" />
                    <option value="lbs">lbs</option>
                    <option value="kg">kg</option>
                </select>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var kg = 0.45359237

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#weight_unit").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "kg") {
        ($("#weight_value").val( $("#weight_value").val()*kg))
    } else {
        $("#weight_value").val( $("#weight_value").val()/kg)
    }
  });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `Math.round()` ?

Comment: This answer seems like it might answer your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/19722641/4297364

Comment: Another similar answer, using `toFixed()` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762768/javascript-math-round-to-two-decimal-places#answer-15762794

Answer (score 0):

Use math round

```
 Math.round($("#weight_value").val()*1000)/1000
```