# How to round a number with multiple decimal places. Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that can take a number and the number of decimal places and round the number to the exact decimal places that are going to be given.
I am using `parseInt(prompt())` in order to gave the number and the number of decimal places.

For example,

```
round(3.141519, 2) -> 3.14
round(5986.32456, 4) -> 5986.3246
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Google: [site:stackoverflow.com javascript round to decimal](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript+round+to+decimal)

Comment: Can't you use Math.round? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript math, round to two decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762768/javascript-math-round-to-two-decimal-places)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting a number with exactly two decimals in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/formatting-a-number-with-exactly-two-decimals-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short function that will allow you to specify the precision and returns a number:

```
function round(number, places) {
   number = parseFloat(number, 10);
   var e  = parseInt(places || 2, 10);
   var m = Math.pow(10, e);
   return Math.floor(number * m) / m;
}
```

Or a slightly shorter ES6 function:

```
const round = (number, places=2) => {
   const m = Math.pow(10, places);
   return Math.floor(number * m) / m;
}
```

Comment: I used the first solution, and when i run the function it gives me NaN.

Comment: Shouldn't it print out the rounded number with as many decimal places that i want?

Comment: @Leo Are you not passing it numbers? `round(3.1456, 3)` works for me...

Comment: I updated my first solution to use `parseFloat` and `parseInt` in case you pass it strings

Comment: I guess i am doing something wrong with my solution.. I can't figure out what.

Comment: function round(number, places) {
   var number = parseInt(prompt("Please enter number:"));
   var places = parseInt(prompt("Please enter number of decimal places:"));
   var e = places || 2;
   var m = Math.pow(10, e);
   return Math.floor(number * m) / m;
}
document.write(round());

Where is my mistake? Can you tell me?

Comment: Yeah, you are using `parseInt` on the "Please enter a number", that needs to be `parseFloat`. You could also remove the `number` and `places` arguments from the function declaration since you are getting that data using `prompt`

Comment: Thanks! You ROCK! :D

Comment: Glad to help, Leo! :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use toFixed

check the following

```js
 console.log(3.141519.toFixed(2))
 console.log(5986.32456.toFixed(4))
```

Comment: Note, `toFixed` returns a string.