# Rounding up to two decimal place in javascript eg 4.9995 to 4.99 in mathematical way in js

Tags: javascript

How can I convert decimal number to 2 decimal place number?
Example: I want to connvert 4.995 to 4.99 but javascript is returning 5.00.

```js
var price=4.995;
var rounded_price=price.toFixed(2);
console.log(rounded_price);
```

Comment: How is that a question?

Comment: console.log(rounded_price); is returning me 5 however I want to have 4.99. Please assist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript math, round to two decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762768/javascript-math-round-to-two-decimal-places)

Comment: Why 4.99? That would break the maths.

Comment: Rounded `4.995` is `5.00`. No error here. I bet you either don't know what round does or don't want to round.

Comment: how can I get 4.99 then from 4.995????

Comment: that would be wrong way.. is there no way converting 4.999966 to 2 decimal place number??????

Comment: There's no fixed decimal numbers in JS, even `toFixed()` returns a string.

Comment: ok.. I was curious to know this in mathematical way in js.. otherwise other tricks I have already tried :P

Comment: Upvoted question... This is a valid point. `toFixed(2)` **Should** return 4.99 (as in currency for example), but it returns 5.00 (a different monetary value) which is wrong.

Comment: yes it should return 4.99 as I am giving 2 as parameter...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't call it rounding but you can achieve it by:

```js
function trim2Dec(n) {
  return Math.floor(n * 100) / 100;
}

alert(trim2Dec(4.995));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for this as the following:

```js
alert("4.995".replace(/(\d+(\.\d{1,2})?)\d*/, "$1"))
```

Comment: To (mis)Quote: "If you have a problem, and RegEx is your answer - you now have two problems". ;o)

Comment: @allnodcoms If you find yourself having to invent the wheel each time you program, then know you are using JavaScript. In any proper language, this method will be supported by a standard library specification. However, in JavaScript, everyone does what they think is best.

Comment: The number of ways to solve a problem in javascript = n + 1, where n = The number of ways to solve a problem in javascript...

Answer (score 0):

This is Pretty simple check out this code

```js
var price=4.995;
var price1=4.985;
var rounded_price=(Math.round(price*100)/100);
var rounded_price1=(Math.round(price1*100)/100);
console.log("price : "+rounded_price+"       price1 : "+rounded_price1);
```

here at first i am *multiplying* the *price* and then i have divided it with 100..just as we do to find the percentage of any number.

Comment: This is very wrong. If you have a number like `4.015`, then you will get `4`!

Comment: corrected..If you remove that -1 then the code will work fine..but you can not get exact result of 4.991 to 0.999 that will give you a result of 5 becuase its basically crossed the range