# Javascript toFixed not working

Tags: javascript, html

See my code bellow. It should add and substract 0.1 from an input. However it gets an error on the toFixed(2) function when I click on the + button. Why does this not work, when the - button do?

Here is my code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2fq6bhxs/1/).

HTML:

```
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="iLiter-left-minus btn btn-lg btn-info btn-number" data-type="minus" data-field="">-
                </button>
            </span>
            <input type="number" id="iLiter" class="form-control input-number input-lg" value="0.4" min="0.1" max="10">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="iLiter-right-plus btn btn-lg btn-info btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="">
                    +
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
        $('.iLiter-right-plus').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var quantity = parseFloat($('#iLiter').val());
            quantity = quantity.toFixed(2);
            if (quantity < 10.0) {
                quantity = quantity + 0.1;
                quantity = quantity.toFixed(2);
                $('#iLiter').val(quantity);
            }
        });
        $('.iLiter-left-minus').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var quantity = parseFloat($('#iLiter').val());
            quantity = quantity.toFixed(2);
            if (quantity > 0.1) {
                quantity = quantity - 0.1;
                quantity = quantity.toFixed(2);
                $('#iLiter').val(quantity);
            }
        });
```

Comment: `toFixed` convert a `Number` to a `String` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762768/javascript-math-round-to-two-decimal-places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
quantity = +quantity + 0.1;
```

and

```
quantity = +quantity - 0.1; //(here + is optional)
```

in corresponding places in your code. It didn't work for "+" button because "+" means also string concatenation and the results of `"string" + number` is a string `"stringnumber"` and strings don't have "toFixed" method (as it is reflected in the console error message) whereas "-" operator converts string `quantity` into a number and everything works as expected.

Comment: Oh, I get it. I will use Martin's answer, but now it makes sense why the minus worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's try

```
quantity = Number(quantity) + 0.1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are converting the float number (you just parsed with `parseFloat()`) back to a string with `toFixed(2)`. In case of `+` operator, you are passing it something like `0.50.1` which is not a valid numeric string (therefore the error with calling `'0.50.1'.toFixed(2)`).

Call `.toFixed` just once, before updating the HTML value (not before working with the value):

```
$('.iLiter-right-plus').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var quantity = parseFloat($('#iLiter').val());
  if (quantity < 10.0) {
    quantity = quantity + 0.1;
    quantity = quantity.toFixed(2);
    $('#iLiter').val(quantity);
  }
});
$('.iLiter-left-minus').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var quantity = parseFloat($('#iLiter').val());
  if (quantity > 0.1) {
    quantity = quantity - 0.1;
    quantity = quantity.toFixed(2);
    $('#iLiter').val(quantity);
  }
});
```

Updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/2fq6bhxs/2/

Answer (score 1):

Please change your Javascript source to like this

```
        $('.iLiter-right-plus').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var quantity = parseFloat($('#iLiter').val());
            quantity = parseFloat(quantity.toFixed(2));
            if (quantity < 10.0) {
                quantity = quantity + 0.1;
                quantity = quantity.toFixed(2);
                $('#iLiter').val(quantity);
            }
        });
        $('.iLiter-left-minus').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var quantity = parseFloat($('#iLiter').val());
            quantity = parseFloat(quantity.toFixed(2));
            if (quantity > 0.1) {
                quantity = quantity - 0.1;
                quantity = quantity.toFixed(2);
                $('#iLiter').val(quantity);
            }
        });
```

When you use `.toFixed` => your `quantity` will be a string.
So the next `.toFixed` will be not work because `.toFixed` only work with a number