# How to add fraction and whole number number in javascript?

Tags: javascript

for example in javascript addition of 1 + 0.59 is 1.5899999999999999 but I want output of 1.59 which looks right to me.

Comment: please check the following doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762768/javascript-math-round-to-two-decimal-places possible duplicate

Comment: The nearest double to 0.59 is 0.58999999999999996891375531049561686813831329345703125. The rot sets in there. Lots of ways of dealing with this in the duplicate.

Comment: If you need this for currency operations I strongly recommend using a special decimal type or slice your whole numbers into arrays and then do the math on those array items. This could also help: http://floating-point-gui.de/languages/javascript/

Comment: @NicolaeOlariu, yes, it's a good advice.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.toFixed()` to round your number.

```js
alert((1+0.58999999999).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: `22k`  reputation you know that question was a duplicate or not.Don't answer the exact duplicate question.I m not downvoter

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. This seems like good advice to me. Although the answerer could expand more on the reasons.