# Force two decimal places (including padding 0s)

Tags: javascript, numbers, decimal, currency

I've tried basically everything here: [JavaScript math, round to two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762768/javascript-math-round-to-two-decimal-places)

Not only do I want to reduce it to two decimals, but if it's less I need to add a zero.  I'm using `.1` in my examples below.

```js
var base = .1;  //desired result is 0.10
var total;

// the x100/100 method
total = (base * 100) / 100;
console.log(total);  //outputs 0.1

// the .toFixed method
total = (base).toFixed(2);
console.log(total + " (" + typeof total + ")"); //looks right, but it's a string

// unary +()
total = +((base).toFixed(2));
console.log(total); //outputs .1
```

Comment: because you convert it to a number.... numbers do not have significant digits.

Comment: It only makes sense to do that as a string. Numbers are binary floating-point values.

Comment: So you're saying it's impossible to output a trailing zero as a number?

Comment: Thanks @Pointy, your comment was more clear :)

Comment: Yes.  A number like `.1` cannot be represented exactly in binary floating point.

Comment: Makes sense, can you post as an answer?

Comment: Well [this question](/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary) is *almost* a good duplicate, because the best answer is pretty clear and extensive.

Comment: No, that clearly says "At most" and mine specifically mentions padding zeros (which would be *at least*)