# Find whole number and append .00 decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to append `.00` if number is not decimal, however when I try the code below it is changing the whole number to `0.00`. For example, if number is `12,200`, it will change it to `0.00` instead of adding `.00` at the end

```js
$('.total-amount').each(function() {
  var x = Number($(this).val()).toFixed(2);
  $(this).val(x).text(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="total-in-basket">
  <div class="total-description">
    total is:
  </div>
  <div class="total-amount">
    $ 12,200
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.total-amount` does not have a `val()`.  it's not an input.  It does have an `html()` or `text()` though

Comment: `<div>` elements don't have a "value" property, so `.val()` won't return anything.

Comment: I tried changing    ".val()" for     "html()" but I get error "Nan"

Comment: What is expected output>

Comment: The NaN is because you're trying to do math on a string that can't be converted to a number (because it includes commas and a `$`).

Comment: instead of looking for a number I should be looking for a text? and then change it to number?

Comment: `parseFloat("12,200").toFixed(2)` might work depending on your locale (doesnt work for me in NL, comma is our cents seperator)

Comment: Partial duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762768/javascript-math-round-to-two-decimal-places

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some issues:

- a `div` has no `value` attribute so `.val()` will not work. Use `.text()`
- Applying `Number` to something that has a dollar sign or a comma will return `NaN`

You can use `replace` to remove the non-digit characters (but allowing a decimal point), and then feed that to a formatter, provided by `Intl.NumberFormat`:

```js
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
});


$('.total-amount').each(function() {
  var x = $(this).text().replace(/[^\d.]/g, "");
  $(this).text(formatter.format(x));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="total-in-basket">
    <div class="total-description">
             total is:
    </div>
    <div class="total-amount">
           $ 12,200
    </div>
</div>
```