# How to round a result in javascript to 2 places after decimal in a working function?

Tags: javascript, rounding

Many thanks to all who helped me on the functions before- my issue now is i would like the result to round up to only two places after the decimal. I seen some answers but do not understand how to apply them. Thanks to help out a newb!

Example of my results 5.958480999999999

Example of the working functions

```
   function wireOd(valNum) {
      document.getElementById("myResult").innerHTML = valNum * valNum * .7854;

    }

    function cal() {
      var numZero5 = document.getElementById('num05').value;
      var numZero6 = document.getElementById('num06').value;
      var numZero7 = document.getElementById('num07').value;
      var total3 = parseFloat(numZero5) * parseFloat(numZero6) * parseFloat(numZero7) * .7854 * 1.5;
      var p = document.getElementById('total3');
      p.innerHTML = total3;
    }
```

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762768/javascript-math-round-to-two-decimal-places or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places

Comment: It isn't clear whether this question needs `round` or `toFixed`, but it's a duplicate of something either way.

Comment: Here is the html if it helps-<div class="containerTsW">
            <p>
                <h1>Stem Weight Calculation</h1>
              <label>Stem OD</label>
              <input id="stemOd" type="number" placeholder="Stem Diameter"
              oninput="stemOd(this.value)" onchange="stemOd(this.value)">
            </p>
               <p>Pounds Per Foot:  <span id="theSum"></span></p> 
        </div>

Answer (score 1):

For example you can use [`Number.prototype.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) in order to achieve the goal, per the docs:

> The toFixed() method formats a number using fixed-point notation.

Like the following:

```js
const result = 5.95848099999999;
console.log(result.toFixed(2));
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, but if the result is different every time how can i write the script? The result i gave will never be the same value- dependant on the user input values.

Comment: I think you have the line `var total3 = parseFloat(numZero5) * parseFloat(numZero6) * parseFloat(numZero7) * .7854 * 1.5;` where you define the value for representation, so in the next line, you could use something like: `p.innerHTML = total3.toFixed(2);`. I hope that helps!

Comment: @norbitrial- that worked great thank you for the expertise- i have one last question my other function -  how would i get the same result in this function? -  function wireOd(valNum) {
      document.getElementById("myResult").innerHTML = valNum * valNum * .7854;
      
    }

Comment: Just simply use `document.getElementById("myResult").innerHTML = (valNum * valNum * .7854).toFixed(2);` in the function. Or store in a variable and call the `toFixed()` function on that.