# How can I return text with useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am waiting for the data (when the user submit) i fetch the data then return the Temperature with useState() but i wanted to return a header with it like `Temperature:12°C`.

Something else is that i wanna round the temperature to 2 decimal places but i don't know how to do so

here is my code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react'
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import './style.css'
import rain from './use1.png'


  function App() {

    
    const [name,setName] = useState('Cairo')
    const [res, setRes] = useState(null)
    const [pic, setPic] = useState(null)
    const [temp, setTemp] = useState('')


  const getApi = e => {


axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${name}&appid=my_key`)
.then(response=> {
  console.log(response.data);
  setRes(response.data.name)


  setTemp(response.data.main.feels_like-273.15+'°C');
  Math.round(temp)
  setPic(`https://openweathermap.org/img/w/${response.data.weather[0].icon}.png`)

})}

const handleChange = e => {
  setName(e.target.value);
};



  return (
<div>
  <img className="wallpaper" src={rain}></img>
  <div className="content">
    <input placeholder="Search.." className="input" onChange={handleChange}></input>

<a href="#" type="submit" onClick={getApi}><i  id="icon" className="fa fa-search"></i></a>


    </div>

  <div className="content2">
    <h1 className="name">{res}</h1>
    <img src={pic}></img>
    <h1 className="temp">{temp}</h1>
  </div>

</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to `setTemp()` before you receive the fetched data. You will need to show more code and also identify any errors you are seeing in dev tools console. See [ask] and [mre]

Comment: just added the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like:

```
`Temperature ${(response.data.main.feels_like-273.15).toFixed(2)} °C`
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a useEffect hook so your component re-renders after your `temp` state changes.

```
useEffect(() => {}, [temp]);
```

In order to round to two decimal places...well, usually I don't like telling people this but that's an extremely easy thing to find out from just using Google or another search engine.

[JavaScript math, round to two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762768/javascript-math-round-to-two-decimal-places)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
 const [temp, setTemp] = useState('')
     setTemp(response.data.main.feels_like-273.15+'°C');
        return (
    <div>
        <h1 className="temp"> Temperature {temp?.toFix(2)}</h1>
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you please provide the full component's code, or at least where is `response` coming from? Anyway, If the response is being passed from a parent component, then I see no reason to use useState at all.

But if you are fetching the data in the same component, then you need to fetch the data asynchronously:

```
function component(){
    const [temp, setTemp] = useState('Loading temperature...')

    useEffect(() => {
       fetchTemp().then((response) => {
          setTemp(response.data.main.feels_like-273.15+'°C');
       })
    }, [])

    
    return (
        <div>
          <h1 className="temp">{temp}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

About rounding the number, you can use `toFixed(decimals)` method.

Example:

```js
let number = 900.1234
console.log(number.toFixed(2))
```