# tofixed gives result inconsistently in different browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, mozilla, rounding

```
var num = 20.025;
num.toFixed(2) - In mozila and chrome gives 20.02
num.toFixed(2) - In IE gives - 20.03 - which is correct.
```

How to get the same value as IE in other browsers. please suggest

Comment: Looks like a fractional representation issue - in Chrome, 20.025 * 100 comes out as 2002.4999999999998

Comment: Thanks Evan Knowles, solution got  from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015027/javascript-tofixed-not-rounding