# divide a floating number, rounding it to 2 decimals, and calculate the remainder

Tags: javascript

say i have the following number 2,74.

If you divide this number by 4, the result is 0.685.

I want to divide this number by 4 but the result should be rounded to 2 decimals.
So my result should be:

3 times 0.69
and a remainder of 0.67

Does anyone have a clue how to do that in javascript? I have absolutely no idea how i should tackle this.

Comment: parseFloat(2.74 -3*parseFloat(2.74 / 4).toFixed(2)).toFixed(2)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way you could do this :

```
var n = 2.74
var x = (n / 4).toFixed(2)
// renders string "0.69"
var r = (n - 3 * parseFloat(x, 10)).toFixed(2)
// renders string "0.67"
```

Explanation :

- method `(n).toFixed(x)` takes the number `n` with its `x` first digits, and returns a string
- method `parseFloat(s, b)` takes a string `s` and returns a floating point number in base `b`

Comment: Nice and easy +1. I would advise against using toFixed and going for the method rossipedia provided

Comment: May I ask what you dislike about the `toFixed` method ?

Comment: it has some problems with rounding for certain numbers. This is due to how floating point numbers work. This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015027/javascript-tofixed-not-rounding for example explains it

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking for 2 digits of precision, you want to multiply the number by `10^2` (100) and then round to the nearest integer by calling `Math.round`. Then divide the result by the same factor you multiplied by (100).

If you want more digits of precision (after the decimal point), then just multiply/divide by larger powers of 10 (eg: 3 digits would be 1000, 4 would be 10000, etc).

```js
var n = 2.74;
var result = Math.round((n / 4) * 100) / 100;

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = (result * 3).toString() + '<br>' + (n - (result*3));
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Another option as mentioned in the comments to your question would be to use `toFixed`:

```
var n = 2.74;
var result = (n/4).toFixed(2) * 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with test if remainder is necessary.

```js
function getParts(num, parts, precision) {
    var v = +(num / parts).toFixed(precision),
        r = +(num - v * (parts - 1)).toFixed(precision);
    return v === r ? { parts: parts, value: v } : { parts: parts - 1, value: v, remainder: r };
}
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getParts(2.74, 4, 2), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getParts(3, 4, 2), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getParts(4, 3, 2), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```