# rounding with toFix

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, getelementbyid

I have a loop that runs perfectly. The toFix() method trims to the correct decimal place but does not round. Why would that be?

I'm using ColdFusion as well with it to fill in some variables. Thanks

```
document.getElementById('flowinput#forminputdata#').value=(parseFloat(velocity#forminputdata#) * parseFloat(distance#forminputdata#) * parseFloat(depth#forminputdata#)).toFixed(4);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript toFixed Not Rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015027/javascript-tofixed-not-rounding)

Answer (score 4):

`toFixed()` takes the number, converts it to a string, and returns the given amount of decimal places. In order to round the number, you'd want to use `toPrecision()`.

Here is the [Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision) on that function.