# JS numObj.toFixed() inconsistent rounding

Tags: javascript, floating-point, tofixed

0.35.toFixed(1) is rounding Down to 0.3

```
while 0.25.toFixed(1) is rounding Up also to 0.3 

Checked for some other floats too.

let a=2.35.toFixed(1) // Returns '2.4'. Note it rounds up
let b=2.55.toFixed(1) // Returns '2.5'. Note it rounds down
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript toFixed Not Rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015027/javascript-tofixed-not-rounding)