# How properly round a number?

Tags: javascript

I need to round or fix it somehow, so the numbers comes out properly in the form.
I have tried to use `toPrecision()`, but I`ve never done it before and can't find a good understandable way to use it. On the screenshot is my issue.

[image: this is a problem I got]

```js
const priceSmall = 4.00;
const priceMedium = 5.00;
const priceLarge = 7.00;
const priceToppings = 0.50; 
const pst = .07;
const gst = .07
let subtotal = 0;

////////////////Pizza size calculation///////////////
function calculateSize(element) {
  if (element == null) {
    return;
  }
  switch(element.value) {
    case "10":
      subtotal = priceSmall;
      break;
    case "12":
      subtotal = priceMedium;
      break;
    case "15":
      subtotal = priceLarge;
      break;
  }
    recalculateTotal();
}
/////////////Topping calculation////////////
function toppingOptionPrice(element) {
  if (element.checked) {
      subtotal += priceToppings;
  } else {
      subtotal -= priceToppings;
  }
    recalculateTotal();
}
  ////////////Total//////////////
function recalculateTotal() {
  let pstToPay = subtotal * pst;
  let gstToPay = subtotal * gst;
  let total = subtotal + pstToPay + gstToPay;

  document.getElementById("subtotal").value = subtotal.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("pstToPay").value = pstToPay.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("gstToPay").value = gstToPay.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("total").value = total.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pizza Order Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
<body>
    <header>
        <img src="media/pizza-served.jpg" width="600" height="277" alt="Pizza Logo"/>
        <h1>Pizza Order Form</h1>
    </header>
        <form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="post" action="http://lavalamp.dyndns.org/~mult114/pizzaorder_olympic.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();" target="_blank">

            <input type="hidden" name="difficulty" value="1" />
            <fieldset id="contactinfo">
                <legend style="font-size: larger;"><strong>Contact Information</strong></legend>
                    <label for="firstnameinput">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="firstnameinput" name="FirstName_tf" /><br>
                    <label for="lastnameinput">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="lastnameinput" name="LastName_tf" /><br>
                    <label for="addrinput">Address</label>
                    <input type="text" id="addrinput" name="Address_tf" /><br>
                    <label for="phoneinput">Phone</label>
                    <input type="text" id="phoneinput" name="Phone_tf" /><br>
                    <label for="emailinput">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" id="emailinput" name="Email_tf" />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="orderinfo">
                <legend style="font-size: larger;"><strong>Order</strong></legend>
                <fieldset id="pizzasize">
                    <legend>Pizza Size</legend>
                        <input type="radio" id="smallsize" name="Size_rg" value="10" onclick="calculateSize(this);">
                        <label for="smallsize">Small 10"</label><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="mediumsize" name="Size_rg" value="12" onclick="calculateSize(this);">  
                        <label for="mediumsize">Medium 12"</label><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="largesize" name="Size_rg" value="15" onclick="calculateSize(this);"> 
                        <label for="largesize">Large 15"</label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="toppingbox">
                    <legend>Topping(s)</legend>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="anchovies" name="Anchovies_cb" value="yes" onclick="toppingOptionPrice(this);">
                        <label for="anchovies">Anchovies</label><br>

                        <input type="checkbox" id="doublecheese" name="DoubleCheese_cb" value="yes" onclick="toppingOptionPrice(this);">
                        <label for="doublecheese">Double Cheese</label><br>

                        <input type="checkbox" id="pepperoni" name="Pepperoni_cb" value="yes" onclick="toppingOptionPrice(this);">
                        <label for="pepperoni">Pepperoni</label><br>

                        <input type="checkbox" id="mushrooms" name="Mushroom_cb" value="yes" onclick="toppingOptionPrice(this);">
                        <label for="mushrooms">Mushrooms</label><br>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="instructions">
                    <legend>Special Instructions</legend>
                        <textarea id="textarea" name="instructions" rows="5" cols="50" placeholder="Enter your message here!(special requests, delivery details, etc.)"></textarea>
                </fieldset>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="payments">
                <legend style="font-size: larger;"><strong>Payment</strong></legend>
                <label>Select Payment Method:</label>
                    <select id="paymethods" name="Payment_menu" required="required">
                        <option value="select">- Select One -</option>
                        <option value="cash">Cash</option>
                        <option value="debit">Debit</option>
                        <option value="credit">Credit Card</option>
                     </select>
            </fieldset>
            
            <fieldset id="calcprice">
                <legend style="font-size: larger;"><strong>Order Total</strong></legend>

                    <label for="subtotal">SubTotal $:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="subtotal" name="SubTotal_tb" readonly><br>
                    <label for="pstToPay">PST $:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="pstToPay" name="PST_tb" readonly><br>
                    <label for="gstToPay">GST $:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="gstToPay" name="GST_tb" readonly><br>
                    <label for="total">Total $:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="total" name="Total_tb" readonly><br>

            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit_but">
        </form>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at [How to round to at most 2 decimal places, if necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/how-to-round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-if-necessary)

Comment: The image you've attached already explains what needs to be done. ---> _(1) Round the GST and PST separately._ . So, instead of `let pstToPay = subtotal * pst`, please try: `let pstToPay = Math.round((subtotal * pst) * 100)/100;`. Same with GST as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is correct. you are getting wrong because of the calculation. Try with this equation:-

```
let pstToPay = subtotal * pst;
pstToPay = parseFloat(pstToPay.toFixed(2));
let gstToPay = subtotal * gst;
gstToPay = parseFloat(gstToPay.toFixed(2));
```

And if you want to remove zeroes you can solve it by this:

```
.toFixed(2).replace(/0+$/, "") // this will make 4.50 = 4.5
```

```js
const priceSmall = 4.00;
const priceMedium = 5.00;
const priceLarge = 7.00;
const priceToppings = 0.50; 
const pst = .07;
const gst = .07
let subtotal = 0;

////////////////Pizza size calculation///////////////
function calculateSize(element) {
  if (element == null) {
    return;
  }
  switch(element.value) {
    case "10":
      subtotal = priceSmall;
      break;
    case "12":
      subtotal = priceMedium;
      break;
    case "15":
      subtotal = priceLarge;
      break;
  }
    recalculateTotal();
}
/////////////Topping calculation////////////
function toppingOptionPrice(element) {
  if (element.checked) {
      subtotal += priceToppings;
  } else {
      subtotal -= priceToppings;
  }
    recalculateTotal();
}
  ////////////Total//////////////
function recalculateTotal() {
  let pstToPay = subtotal * pst;
  pstToPay = parseFloat(pstToPay.toFixed(2));
  let gstToPay = subtotal * gst;
  
    gstToPay = parseFloat(gstToPay.toFixed(2));

  let total = subtotal +pstToPay + gstToPay;
      document.getElementById("subtotal").value = subtotal.toFixed(2).replace(/0+$/, "") ;
  document.getElementById("pstToPay").value = pstToPay.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("gstToPay").value = gstToPay.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("total").value = total.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pizza Order Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
<body>
    <header>
        <img src="media/pizza-served.jpg" width="600" height="277" alt="Pizza Logo"/>
        <h1>Pizza Order Form</h1>
    </header>
        <form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="post" action="http://lavalamp.dyndns.org/~mult114/pizzaorder_olympic.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();" target="_blank">

            <input type="hidden" name="difficulty" value="1" />
            <fieldset id="contactinfo">
                <legend style="font-size: larger;"><strong>Contact Information</strong></legend>
                    <label for="firstnameinput">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="firstnameinput" name="FirstName_tf" /><br>
                    <label for="lastnameinput">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="lastnameinput" name="LastName_tf" /><br>
                    <label for="addrinput">Address</label>
                    <input type="text" id="addrinput" name="Address_tf" /><br>
                    <label for="phoneinput">Phone</label>
                    <input type="text" id="phoneinput" name="Phone_tf" /><br>
                    <label for="emailinput">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" id="emailinput" name="Email_tf" />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="orderinfo">
                <legend style="font-size: larger;"><strong>Order</strong></legend>
                <fieldset id="pizzasize">
                    <legend>Pizza Size</legend>
                        <input type="radio" id="smallsize" name="Size_rg" value="10" onclick="calculateSize(this);">
                        <label for="smallsize">Small 10"</label><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="mediumsize" name="Size_rg" value="12" onclick="calculateSize(this);">  
                        <label for="mediumsize">Medium 12"</label><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="largesize" name="Size_rg" value="15" onclick="calculateSize(this);"> 
                        <label for="largesize">Large 15"</label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="toppingbox">
                    <legend>Topping(s)</legend>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="anchovies" name="Anchovies_cb" value="yes" onclick="toppingOptionPrice(this);">
                        <label for="anchovies">Anchovies</label><br>

                        <input type="checkbox" id="doublecheese" name="DoubleCheese_cb" value="yes" onclick="toppingOptionPrice(this);">
                        <label for="doublecheese">Double Cheese</label><br>

                        <input type="checkbox" id="pepperoni" name="Pepperoni_cb" value="yes" onclick="toppingOptionPrice(this);">
                        <label for="pepperoni">Pepperoni</label><br>

                        <input type="checkbox" id="mushrooms" name="Mushroom_cb" value="yes" onclick="toppingOptionPrice(this);">
                        <label for="mushrooms">Mushrooms</label><br>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="instructions">
                    <legend>Special Instructions</legend>
                        <textarea id="textarea" name="instructions" rows="5" cols="50" placeholder="Enter your message here!(special requests, delivery details, etc.)"></textarea>
                </fieldset>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="payments">
                <legend style="font-size: larger;"><strong>Payment</strong></legend>
                <label>Select Payment Method:</label>
                    <select id="paymethods" name="Payment_menu" required="required">
                        <option value="select">- Select One -</option>
                        <option value="cash">Cash</option>
                        <option value="debit">Debit</option>
                        <option value="credit">Credit Card</option>
                     </select>
            </fieldset>
            
            <fieldset id="calcprice">
                <legend style="font-size: larger;"><strong>Order Total</strong></legend>

                    <label for="subtotal">SubTotal $:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="subtotal" name="SubTotal_tb" readonly><br>
                    <label for="pstToPay">PST $:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="pstToPay" name="PST_tb" readonly><br>
                    <label for="gstToPay">GST $:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="gstToPay" name="GST_tb" readonly><br>
                    <label for="total">Total $:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="total" name="Total_tb" readonly><br>

            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit_but">
        </form>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: May be [this info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59268677/13658816) about `.toFixed()` is helpful to consider? FWIW, the image in the question does not seem tto indicate that the numbers need to be padded. It is okay with `4.5` instead of `4.50` - so, the idea to deliberately pad a zero (using `.toFixed`) and then use regex to undo the padded zero does not seem mandatory in this particular context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use math.round() function available in js to round your values.
For example say your total value can be rounded of by providing math.round() func to it.
let total = math.round(subtotal + pstToPay + gstToPay);

Reference page:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round