# Javascript multiplication

Tags: javascript, multiplication

I'm using Google Chrome.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function DoThis()
            {
                var value = 1.005;
                var multiplied = value * 100;
                alert(multiplied);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="DoThis();">

    </body>
</html>
```

multiplied ends up coming out as 100.49999999 instead of 100.5

Anyone have an explanation?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406494/javascript-multiplying-incorrectly-causing-incorrect-rounding

Answer (score 0):

All numbers in Javascript are stored as floats. You're seeing one of the limittions of float arithmetic.