# Adding fraction with integers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, addition, fractions

Here is what my friend noticed while working on a project. He does not have any stackoverflow account so I am asking on behalf of my friend.

```
var a = 1.75/3;
```

so it gives

```
a = 0.5833333333333334
```

Now when I add 1 to variable a I get this:

```
1.5833333333333335
```

Notice the difference in the last digits

Similarly when I do following

```
    0.5833333333333336+1
```

I get

```
    1.5833333333333335
```

Now replacing the `6` with `7`

it gives me

```
1.5833333333333337
```

I can't understand what is going here. Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: This should help http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: It's an issue in Javascript with floating point numbers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem

Comment: It's a common question here for JS. [Try searching for it](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BJavaScript%5D+decimal+arithmetic).

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480699/understanding-floating-point-variables

Comment: Check out [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken).